# inner join three tables results in multiplied values

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

I'm trying to (let's say) gather a report on customers.
In that report I want to include sum of orders and ticket number for each client.

Tables:

```
Customer(id, name)
Order(id, customer_id, amount)
support_ticket(id, customer_id)
```

query:

```
select 
  c.id as 'Customer', 
  count(distinct t.id) as "Ticket count", 
  count(distinct o.id) as "Order count", 
  sum(o.amount) as 'Order Amount' 

from customer as c
  inner join `order` as o on c.id = o.customer_id
  inner join support_ticket as t on c.id = t.customer_id

group by c.id
```

Since I join with customer.id on the two tables, I get all the rows "duplicated", since I get all possible combinations, so if the client as multiple tickets, the `sum(o.amount)` will we multiplied because of "duplicated rows"

sqlFiddle (mysql): http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ba39ba/13

sqlFiddle (pg): http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/bc32e/7

It seems like a simple case but I've been looking at it too much I think, I can't find the proper way to do that report.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your best bet is to re-write the Aggregation off the Order table as as Derived Table;

EG

```
select 
  c.id as 'Customer', 
  count(distinct t.id) as "Ticket count", 
  o.amount as 'Order Amount' ,
  o.[Order count]
from customer as c
  inner join 
  (SELECT 
    o.customer_id, 
    sum(amount) as amount , 
    count(distinct o.id) as "Order count" 
    from [order] 
    group by o.customer_id)
   as o on c.id = o.customer_id
  inner join support_ticket as t on c.id = t.customer_id

group by 
  c.id , 
  o.amount ,
  o.[Order count]
```

Note that the Derived Table Columns then are added to the group by clause at the bottom.

Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

Just calculate `order` values in a sub-query and join it.

```
SELECT
  c.id as 'Customer'
  ,count(DISTINCT st.id) as 'Ticket Count'
  ,o.`Order Count`
  ,o.amount as `Order Amount`
FROM customer c
INNER JOIN support_ticket st
  on c.id = st.customer_id
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT 
    customer_id
    ,SUM(amount) as 'amount'
    ,count(distinct id) as 'Order Count'
  FROM `order`
  group by customer_id
) o
  on c.id = o.customer_id
GROUP BY c.id;
```

Comment: What if you have 2 identical Amount values for the same Cust ID?

Comment: In case I'm not being clear - I'm saying that the above answer is incorrect. If you have 2 orders for cust id of $100 each then sum(distinct Amount) = $100 which is patently wrong (correct sum is $200) - Be very careful with using DISTINCT.

Comment: You just copied my answer! & you forgot to add the columns to the group by clause! - "See me after class"

Comment: I didn't copied anything ... Is just the simple logic and I don't need any group by. Now have a good day as I don't have time to waste!

Comment: You can't aggregate 1 column -count (distinct std.id) without grouping by all the other columns... This is SQL 101 stuff.

Comment: @johnMcTighe I'm pretty sure mysql accepts aggregate on specific columns only, but I'd indeed like a solution that is accepted on more database systems

Answer (score 1):

```
select c.id as 'Customer'
      ,t2.count_ticket as "Ticket count"
      ,t1.count_order as "Order count"
      ,t1.amount as 'Order Amount' 
from customer as c
inner join (select customer_id
                  ,count(id) as count_order
                  ,sum(amount) as amount 
            from Order group by customer_id) t1  
on c.id = t1.customer_id
inner join (select customer_id
                  ,count(id) as count_ticket 
            from support_ticket group by customer_id) t2
on c.id = t2.customer_id
```

Answer (score 1):

In cases like yours, when I think the solution of my problem should be fairly simple but I cant wrap my head around it, I tend to use a `WITH` clause.

Not because its better, but because it helps me to understand my code better by splitting up complexity. First I create a relatively simple temp. Solving the first part of my problem.

```
WITH temp AS (
 SELECT
    c.id AS "customer",
    COUNT(DISTINCT o.id) AS "order_count",
    SUM(o.amount) AS "order_amount"
 FROM customer AS c
 INNER JOIN  "order" AS o on c.id = o.customer_id
 GROUP BY c.id
)
```

Then I simply select the first half of my solution from temp, adding this way all intermediate results, and solve the second part of my initial sql.

```
SELECT
    temp.customer,
    COUNT(DISTINCT t.id) as "ticket_count",
    temp.order_count,
    temp.order_amount
FROM temp
INNER JOIN support_ticket as t on temp.customer = t.customer_id
GROUP BY temp.customer, temp.order_count, temp.order_amount
```

The principle is the same like in all previous answers, but `SELECTS` are separated and I can check them fast, and continue on if I'm happy with parts of the solution.